# ionic cordova media plugin recorded file on android is downloaded to iPhone but couldn't play : Error code 4 with no message

Tags: iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, media, recording

cordova-plugin-media 3.0.1 (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/)

My application uses it to record audio on android then upload it to the back-end using file transfer plugin , 
then download it to iPhone using file transfer plugin , but the file can not play and got err code:4 with no message ,

- the same is working well if the file is recorded on iPhone  ,
  like  'http://cpham.perso.univ-pau.fr/SmartSantanderSample/test.m4a'.
- when using HTTP URL for remote sample , its working also .

I've tried:

- to add a mime type while uploading the recorded file from android to the server.
- to add extension to the file name before uploading .
- to set the content type header on the server response while downloading the file.
- to test several versions of the plugin.
- to use several and different file extensions for the file .
- to add/remove extensions to/from the file when downloaded .

  play() {

  ```
  this.pf.ready().then(() => {

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    let fileKey = "AMIfv95xPQjnvzuf-d6Ne5LHNLCuhDt7GnrxvvZCJcKgYl7i2inVFJDXmPuT-dW5Dydjr2_1q0zNzXS-zjJ1qWszJjyxWs8A6Z0YUpCnEABICNzxeHrCkARRZiHCqtj-v0gyI5d-vOAKiXL7lXzsFLsy-1o6N8_cPJuHCIiv2WKAaRpN_oHAtXtBiBln5V9NhNFicUwK-zxItSUvgg5-WZqj3kHxUMDzVLw_BJOQSGWZ8p05NfYENvsCNCgI0F9DkcgLXqsZjz0_fcWbkS0h_RSfEHMJUM94C7T8wyWQDyXy1xpeFwFB2fA80KWv4W3UACs8D38U4p60ejoOcbpyvEXhQ2wzBr64ot5eyEiKrwp66BGZQV8hrBWQyjCJNnN-1iGXI_GWi0h5nb3yEm1TY5GjFHoPk1QGGBUx0kVKvoGl0ZTHdP5_4UA";
  ```

  const url =  "https://xxxxxxxx.appspot.com/DownloadService?fileKey=" + fileKey;

  ```
    fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.documentsDirectory + "file").then((entry) => {
      let pl: MediaObject = this.media.create(entry.toInternalURL());
      pl.onStatusUpdate.subscribe(status => alert(status)); 
      pl.onSuccess.subscribe(() => console.log('Action is successful'));
      pl.onError.subscribe(error => alert('Error!' + JSON.stringify(error)));
      pl.play({numberOfLoops:1,playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked:true});

    }, (error) => {
      alert(" Err : " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

  })
  ```

  }

Please any advise or suggestion .

Thanks in advance